# Modem router as router

Tags: networking, router

So I had this crazy idea that I'm not sure is possible.

I have a modem router (GPON ONT) with 4 ethernet port and 1 WAN port (fiber optic) from ISP :

All ethernet ports is for LAN devices under the GPON ONT, but it has been changed by the ISP so it does the following :

Port number #1 is for LAN (GPON ONT GUI can only be accessed through this port)
Port number #2 and #3 is in Bridge mode (this cannot be changed, hardcoded from the ISP)
Port number #4 is for IPTV (it has its own VLAN and this cannot be changed, hardcoded from the ISP)

I connect port #4 to STB and port #3 to OpenWRT router.

Topo :
[image]

This GPON ONT have USB slot in it and it's strong enough to power my USB HDD. I want to be able to access this HDD from my LAN (like NAS).

But the problem is this GPON ONT is not in my LAN. So I thought it's going to be easy because port #1 is available, I could just plug ethernet cable from OpenWRT router to GPON ONT port #1

[image]

But it does not work. I checked the DHCP list in the OpenWRT and the GPON ONT didn't get any IP. Here's my GPON ONT settings :

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ZRvSvmD.png]

So is it possible?

Comment: Your `GPON ONT` is going to be assigned an ip address by your router, that is not possible, your ISP is assigning it's ip address.

Comment: Actually it's possible, I just achieve this by setting the static IP on GPON to match the network address in OpenWRT, point the gateway to OpenWRT IP address and plug ethernet cable to one of OpenWRT ethernet port and the other on GPON ethernet port.